# Can I share global variables when calling pytest from Python code

Tags: python, pytest

I am calling pytest from Python code like below

```
import pytest

global_var = "something I like to share as a global variable"
pytest.main()
```

Is there any way my test code has access to `global_var`?
If the answer is no, what are the good options to share data between caller program and my tests?

I know I can write data into a file, but I am hoping to find some better "in memory" options.

Comment: You can use fixtures with scope=module. Or put your data in os environ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the attribute to `pytest`

```
pytest.global_var = 'something I like to share as a global variable'
pytest.main()
```

And in the test

```
print(pytest.global_var) # something I like to share as a global variable
```