# Pytest: how to execute some code once at the start of when each test_file.py is called?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, pytest-cov

My test repository is like so:

```
-Test:
    - common_library.py
    - conftest.py
    - Feature_folder_01:
        - test_file_01.py
        - test_file_02.py
    - Feature_folder_02:
        - test_file_01.py
        - test_file_02.py
        - test_file_02.py
```

I want to execute some code at the beginning of each test_file_*.py.
I cannot have the code in conftest.py because the code for some basic calls (serial_
command class) e.g. serial read-write is in common_library.py and conftest is compiled first. So it does not have access to the calls in common-library. If a fixture is used the fixture will have to be copied at that start of each test_file_*.py (there are several) and it will be executed for every parameterization of the tests.

Is there a possible solution to this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't simply place an appropriate fixture in `conftest.py`. If you need facilities from `common_library.py`, just `import` it in `conftest.py`.

Comment: I get a circular import error because common_library uses a config parameter , e.g. serial port numbers, that are fetched by conftest

Comment: This sounds like you just have to fix your cyclic import problem. Without seeing your code (or a minimal version of it) it is unclear what the actual problem is.

Comment: The cyclic import problem is caused because conftest is imported in common_library to get access to the serial port that's sent as an argument to the pytest run command. It is referenced in common_library as conftest.ttyport -which is opened and initialized once when the command class in common-library is called. Perhaps there is another way to get access to conftest.ttyport???

Comment: Importing `conftest.py` is generally not a good idea. If you have a function that is needed in both modules, move it to the common library. If the common library contains fixtures that rely on `conftest.py` (it shouldn't), move them to `conftest.py`. Basically, `conftest.py` should only contain fixtures and hooks, and supporting functions only needed by these.

Comment: I could try that. Alternatively, is there a way to run some default code when a class is instantiated?

Comment: For what I understand, you just have to move `ttyport` to the common library and set it there from `conftest.py`. As the respective hook is called before anything in the tests, it will be guaranteed to be set once it is needed in your class initialization.

Comment: I have refactoring conftest.py and common library. One problem that I ran into was not being able to access arguments from conftest.py. i.e open ttyport in the common library, ttyport is a command line argument parsed in conftest.py. I used the approach outlined here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67480211/can-i-share-global-variables-when-calling-pytest-from-python-code. I get the error: module pytest has no attribute ttyport